# Fortran operator precedence error for exponent with ifort

Tags: fortran, operator-precedence, intel-fortran

I am getting different behavior between Portland and Intel fortran compilers when evaluating a simple expression with an exponent followed by a multiply. I am pretty sure that pgf90 (and gfortran) are working correctly based on my understanding of operator precedence, but I would like a second opinion since these things can get a bit tricky.

Here is my code simplified down to a very basic form. When run with ifort the expression of the form `d1=a**-2*b` gets interpretted as `d1=a**(-2*b)` by ifort by as `d1=(a**-2)*b` by pgf90 and gfortran. If I remove the negative sign from the exponent, all three compilers interpret this as `d1=(a**2)*b`. If I change *b to +b I also get good behavior from all three.

```
program badvals
  implicit none
  real :: a, b, c1, c2, d1, d2

  a = 2.
  b = 4.

  ! Works with addition following the exponent.
  c1 = a**-2+b
  c2 = a**(-2)+b

  ! Ifort differs with multiplication following negative exponent.
  d1 = a**-2*b
  d2 = a**(-2)*b

  print*, "c1, d1       = ",c1, d1
  print*, "c2, d2       = ",c1, d2
  print*, "c2-c1, d2-d1 = ",c2-c1, d2-d1
end program badvals

!Program output for ifort v13.0.1.117: (either -O0 or -fast):
! c1, d1       =    4.250000      3.9062500E-03
! c2, d2       =    4.250000       1.000000
! c2-c1, d2-d1 =   0.0000000E+00  0.9960938

!Program output for pgf90 v12.10-0: (either -O0 or -fast):
! c1, d1       =     4.250000        1.000000
! c2, d2       =     4.250000        1.000000
! c2-c1, d2-d1 =     0.000000        0.000000

!Program output for gfortran v4.1.2: (either -O0 or -O3):
! c1, d1       =    4.250000       1.000000
! c2, d2       =    4.250000       1.000000
! c2-c1, d2-d1 =    0.000000       0.000000
```

Is there a history behind these differences so that they should be considered a "feature"? Or, is this an outright bug on Intel's part?

Comment: So, based on the response from MSB and IanH, this would be a "feature" of ifort. In general, what I take home from this is that I need to add the rule "don't put two arithmetic operators next to each other" to my thinking. And as always, be generous with the parentheses. The link provided by IanH is really helpful to understand what is happening in ifort's mind. The different behavior I see when changing the * to a + is because the unary +- precedence falls between * and the binary +-.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching the web, I find that statement that two consecutive operators are not allowed.  Therefore  interpreting rather than rejecting this expression is an extension to the language.  That extension has been implemented differently by different compiler vendors.

Indeed, when I use gfortran with restrictive compiler options, it rejects this code example:

```
badvals.f90:9.11:
  c1 = a**-2+b
           1
Error: Extension: Unary operator following arithmetic operator (use parentheses) at (1)
badvals.f90:13.11:

  d1 = a**-2*b
           1
Error: Extension: Unary operator following arithmetic operator (use parentheses) at (1)
```

Similarly, ifort with restrictive compiler options provides the following:

```
badvals.f90(9): warning #7026: Non-standard extension
  c1 = a**-2+b
----------^
badvals.f90(13): warning #7026: Non-standard extension
  d1 = a**-2*b
----------^
```

So:
1) using the warning and error options of the compiler can be very helpful,
2) its more of an extension than a bug,
3) even if this expression were allowed by the language, gfortran's advice is good -- use parentheses for clarity even if not required.

Comment: "two consecutive operators are not allowed" needs a little qualification - it applies here because of the syntax rules for level two expressions (the arithmetic ones) but not generally... `to_be .or. .not. to_be` is ok (and was quite common in Shakespearean Fortran) and you could slip a defined unary operator in there too.  If the OP wants a formal description of the extension, they can read [this](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-win/GUID-A03254E4-36D6-4CFC-9DF6-AD264BB6C820.htm).

Comment: What are these restrictive options?